# Retrofit: Request from full url, return error

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I build the project with retrofit-2.2.0. I wanted to request a full url, but that is failed

```
public interface FileRetrofitServer {
@Streaming
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileAsync(@Url String fileUrl);
}
```

it return the message as the below:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Base URL required.

Comment: You need to pass full url instead of passing segment of full url.
like **www.yourdemain.com/api/apiname** . And also check `Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASEURL)`

Comment: I don't know the base url. The full url must be passed by the user. How do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer. Base url must not be empty, you can set a default value, and then the full url will replace the Base url.